# Rows disappearing in grid refresh

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have been spending hours trying to find out why this is happening. I am not sure if there is something wrong in my code or whether this is an ExtJS bug.

I have a **grid** with about 7000 rows in it, so its pretty big. I modify something in all the cells of a column in my grid and then do a **grid.getView().refresh()**. Simple enough, and it all happens in the client side.

However whenever the **grid.getView().refresh()** is called, about 80% of my rows disappear!

The code looks something like this :

```
handler = function () {

    for (var j = 0; j < myGrid.store.data.items.length; j++) {

        var outlet = myGrid.store.data.items[j].data;

        outlet['field'] = 'Hey';
    }

    myGrid.getView().refresh();
}
```

I even simplified it to this:

```
handler = function () {
  myGrid.getView().refresh(); 
}
```

*and the problem still happens!!!*

Unfortunately I can't replicate this in a jsfiddle as such because of the large datasets.

I am using the **bufferedRenderer** plugin which is set to :

```
this.plugins = {
    ptype: 'bufferedrenderer',
    trailingBufferZone: 20,  // Keep 20 rows rendered in the table behind scroll
    leadingBufferZone: 50   // Keep 50 rows rendered in the table ahead of scroll
};
```

Whether this is having an effect or not I have no idea.

Does anyone know what this could be? And what my next steps could be to deduce the problem?

**UPDATE** : It appears to be related to the bufferedrenderer. If I deactivate it then the problem does not occur.

Also what I failed to mention was that the table being refreshed is hidden behind a tabbed pane. So in essence maybe the bufferedRenderer realises that its not important to update because its hidden, or... I dunno. It just gets the bufferedRenderer confused.

**UPDATE** : Here is a fiddle that traps the problem. There are about 5000 rows in the second tab. When I click on the refresh button in the first tab, then 90% of the rows disappear.

http://jsfiddle.net/4nupbosf/5/

*sometimes* the problem doesn't happen. But eventually it will. Just keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

Height of the tabpanel is not defined hence it's zero so is grid height. You only do not see the rows, they are there, just add a height to the tabpanel.

Then, all records in the fiddle have same id - it cannot be.

Then, you create the store with `new` keyword that might cause some problems but not necessarily.

Then, in the code above, you access data of records directly using `data` property. You should never do that. Use `record.set('fieldName', newValue)` instead.

Comment: yes. sorry the fiddle is wrong. I will try to access using record.set(..)

Comment: I updated the fiddle. Now i have the problem perfectly trapped.

Comment: Records still have same ids what can be the cause of the problem. Set it to 1, 2, 3, ... and try again.